# pandas group by & drop symmetric records and get top 2 in case of a tie and max of unique records

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Still cannot figure out how to achieve that or find a better approach:

I have this example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'method':['Car','Bus','Train','Bus','Car','Train','Bus','Car','Train'],
                   'use':[6,6,6,4,3,1,4,4,1]})
```

gives:

```
   customer method  use
0         1    Car    6
1         1    Bus    6
2         1  Train    6
3         2    Bus    4
4         2    Car    3
5         2  Train    1
6         3    Bus    4
7         3    Car    4
8         3  Train    1
```

I have here 3 customers, the first one has all values equal for each method, the second one has 3 different values and the third one has two equal values and one unique value.

I am trying to know what is the most used method for each customer! so in case of customer 1 all are equal so I want to drop this customer as we cannot decide, for the second one it is obvious it will be Bus and for the third one I will pick up the top 2 values since they have equal values in such case Bus & Car.

Now I tried to drop duplicates based on a subset of `customer` and `use` columns to get rid of customers with all equal values within the df:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['customer','use'], keep=False)
```

But this also dropped customer 3 on both indices 6 & 7 so this solution is not working.

I tried another one by calculating the std which will be zero in case of equal values in grouping:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('customer')['use'].std(), on=['customer'], how='left')
```

so I can now drop records with `use_y = 0.000000` and this is the output df2:

```
  customer method  use_x     use_y
3         2    Bus      4  1.527525
4         2    Car      3  1.527525
5         2  Train      1  1.527525
6         3    Bus      4  1.732051
7         3    Car      4  1.732051
8         3  Train      1  1.732051
```

Now to pick the top 2 values in case of a tie and max value if no tie after grouping:

```
df2.sort_values('use_x', ascending=False).groupby('customer').head(2).sort_index()
```

I do not know how to get the max value in grouping of no tie and the nlargest(2) in case of a tie?

**Desired output:**

```
   customer method  use_x     use_y
3         2    Bus      4  1.527525
6         3    Bus      4  1.732051
7         3    Car      4  1.732051
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Hi @ShahabRahnama, I updated the question with the desired output, on use_x column customer 2 has max value is 4 and customer 3 has nlargest(2) because no max in this case of ties. Thanks

Comment: Hi @MTALY, use "drop_duplicates" method with "keep=first" argument, in order to keep the first row and drop others. You may want to checkout document: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Hi @Tahirhan, if I use 'drop_duplicates' with keep first argument, customer #1 & #3 dropped records will give wrong overall results because my focus is on getting the max value of all unique and top 2 in case of ties and drop the whole records if all are equal per customer! hope my explanation makes it clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this could be **NOT** the **best solution** but it does the job if someone would like to know it. I am also still looking for better and efficient ways to do that!

So, I got this dfs after dropping symmetric records per group:

```
   customer method  use_x     use_y
3         2    Bus      4  1.527525
4         2    Car      3  1.527525
5         2  Train      1  1.527525
6         3    Bus      4  1.732051
7         3    Car      4  1.732051
8         3  Train      1  1.732051
```

I have added two columns for ranking using `pandas.DataFrame.rank`:

```
df2['rank-min'] = df2.groupby("customer")['use_x'].rank(method='min')
df2['rank-max'] = df2.groupby("customer")['use_x'].rank(method='max')
```

Which gives:

```
   customer method  use_x     use_y  rank-min  rank-max
3         2    Bus      4  1.527525       3.0       3.0
4         2    Car      3  1.527525       2.0       2.0
5         2  Train      1  1.527525       1.0       1.0
6         3    Bus      4  1.732051       2.0       3.0
7         3    Car      4  1.732051       2.0       3.0
8         3  Train      1  1.732051       1.0       1.0
```

Here is the trick, if `rank-min == rank-max` means it is a unique record **within the group** if not, it means **a repeated record** within the **group**

So, I got the top 2 results per sorted group using head(2):

```
df3 = df2.sort_values('use_x', ascending=False).groupby('customer').head(2).sort_index()
```

To get df3:

```
   customer method  use_x     use_y  rank-min  rank-max
3         2    Bus      4  1.527525       3.0       3.0
4         2    Car      3  1.527525       2.0       2.0
6         3    Bus      4  1.732051       2.0       3.0
7         3    Car      4  1.732051       2.0       3.0
```

then split this df3 to **ties df** and **non ties df**

```
ties = df3[df3['rank-min'] != df3['rank-max']]
non_ties = df3[-(df3['rank-min'] != df3['rank-max'])]
```

Finally, got the `idxmax()` from non_ties:

```
max_unique = non_ties.loc[non_ties.groupby('customer')['use_x'].idxmax()]
```

and concat:

```
output = pd.concat([ties, max_unique])
```

Final output is as expected per group:

```
   customer method  use_x     use_y  rank-min  rank-max
6         3    Bus      4  1.732051       2.0       3.0
7         3    Car      4  1.732051       2.0       3.0
3         2    Bus      4  1.527525       3.0       3.0
```

I know there could be more efficient & elegant ways, but this is my best based on my knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'customer':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'method':['Car','Bus','Train','Bus','Car','Train','Bus','Car','Train'],
                   'use':[6,6,6,4,3,1,4,4,1]})
df = df.merge(df.groupby('customer')['use'].std(), on=['customer'], how='left')


# Drop `use_y` == 0.0
df = df[df.use_y != 0]
# select max or all max rows 
# df[df['use_x'] == df['use_x'].max()]

df[df.groupby(['customer','method'])['use_x'].transform('max') == df['use_x'].max()]
```

Output:

```
   customer method  use_x     use_y
3         2    Bus      4  1.527525
6         3    Bus      4  1.732051
7         3    Car      4  1.732051
```

Comment: Thanks Shahab, your solution gets the output for the whole df records in the example which works but not **by group** so If I have more customers it will not work as expected.

Comment: @MTALY updated. check it ;)